# Utilising Genetic algorithm to overcome different size datasets in model

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, scipy, genetic-algorithm

SO I realise the question I am asking here is large and complex.

#### A potential solution to variences in sizes of

In all of my searching through statistical forums and posts I haven't come across a scientifically sound method of taking into account the type of data that I am encountering,
but I have thought up a (novel?) potential solutions to account perfectly (in my mind) for large and small datasets within the same model.

The proposed method involves using a genetic algorithm to alter two numbers defining a relationship between the size of the dataset making up an `implied strike` rate and the
percentage of the `implied strike` to be used, with the target of the model to maximise the homology of the number `1` in two columns of the following csv. (ultra simplified
but hopefully demonstrates the principle)

#### Example data

```
Date,PupilName,Unique class,Achieved rank,x,y,x/y,Average xy
12/12/2012,PupilName1,UniqueClass1,1,3000,9610,0.312174818,0.08527
12/12/2012,PupilName2,UniqueClass1,2,300,961,0.312174818,0.08527
12/12/2012,PupilName3,UniqueClass1,3,1,3,0.333333333,0.08527
13/12/2012,PupilName1,UniqueClass2,1,2,3,0.666666667,0.08527
13/12/2012,PupilName2,UniqueClass2,2,0,1,0,0.08527
13/12/2012,PupilName3,UniqueClass2,3,0,5,0,0.08527
13/12/2012,PupilName4,UniqueClass2,4,0,2,0,0.08527
13/12/2012,PupilName5,UniqueClass2,5,0,17,0,0.08527
14/12/2012,PupilName1,UniqueClass3,1,1,2,0.5,0.08527
14/12/2012,PupilName2,UniqueClass3,2,0,1,0,0.08527
14/12/2012,PupilName3,UniqueClass3,3,0,5,0,0.08527
14/12/2012,PupilName4,UniqueClass3,4,0,6,0,0.08527
14/12/2012,PupilName5,UniqueClass3,5,0,12,0,0.08527
15/12/2012,PupilName1,UniqueClass4,1,0,0,0,0.08527
15/12/2012,PupilName2,UniqueClass4,2,1,25,0.04,0.08527
15/12/2012,PupilName3,UniqueClass4,3,1,29,0.034482759,0.08527
15/12/2012,PupilName4,UniqueClass4,4,1,38,0.026315789,0.08527
16/12/2012,PupilName1,UniqueClass5,1,12,24,0.5,0.08527
16/12/2012,PupilName2,UniqueClass5,2,1,2,0.5,0.08527
16/12/2012,PupilName3,UniqueClass5,3,13,59,0.220338983,0.08527
16/12/2012,PupilName4,UniqueClass5,4,28,359,0.077994429,0.08527
16/12/2012,PupilName5,UniqueClass5,5,0,0,0,0.08527
17/12/2012,PupilName1,UniqueClass6,1,0,0,0,0.08527
17/12/2012,PupilName2,UniqueClass6,2,2,200,0.01,0.08527
17/12/2012,PupilName3,UniqueClass6,3,2,254,0.007874016,0.08527
17/12/2012,PupilName4,UniqueClass6,4,2,278,0.007194245,0.08527
17/12/2012,PupilName5,UniqueClass6,5,1,279,0.003584229,0.08527
```

So I have created a tiny model dataset, which contains some good examples of where my current methods fall short and how I feel a genetic algorithm can be used to fix this. If we look in the dataset above it contains 6 unique classes the ultimate objective of the algorithm is to create as high as possible correspondence between a rank of an adjusted `x/y` and the `achieved rank` in column 3 (zero based referencing.) In `uniqueclass1` we have two identical `x/y` values, now these are comparatively large `x/y` values if you compare with the average (note the average isn't calculated from this dataset) but it would be common sense to expect that the 3000/9610 is more significant and therefore more likely to have an `achieved rank` of `1` than the 300/961. So what I want to do is make an `adjusted x/y` to overcome these differences in dataset sizes using a logarithmic growth relationship defined by the equation:

`adjusted xy = ((1-exp(-y*α)) * x/y)) + ((1-(1-exp(-y*α)))*Average xy)`

Where `α` is the only dynamic number

If I can explain my logic a little and open myself up to (hopefully) constructive criticsm. This graph below shows is an exponential growth relationship between size of the data set and the % of x/y contributing to the adjusted x/y. Essentially what the above equation says is as the dataset gets larger the percentage of the original `x/y` used in the `adjusted x/y` gets larger. Whatever percentage is left is made up by the average xy. Could hypothetically be 75% `x/y` and 25% `average xy` for 300/961 and 95%/5% for 3000/9610 creating an adjusted x/y which clearly demonstrates

[image: Exponential growth relationship between size of the data set and the % of x/y contributing to the adjusted x/y]

For help with understanding the lowering of `α` would produce the following relationship where by a larger dataset would be requred to achieve the same "% of xy contributed"

[image]

Conversly increasing  `α` would produce the following relationship where by a smaller dataset would be requred to achieve the same "% of xy contributed"

[image]

So I have explained my logic. I am also open to code snippets to help me overcome the problem. I have plans to make a multitude of genetic/evolutionary algorithms in the future and could really use a working example to pick apart and play with in order to help my understanding of how to utilise such abilities of python. If additional detail is required or further clarification about the problem or methods please do ask, I really want to be able to solve this problem and future problems of this nature.

So after much discussion about the methods available to overcome the problem presented here I have come to the conclusion that he best method would be a genetic algorithm to iterate α in order to maximise the homology/correspondance between a rank of an adjusted x/y and the achieved rank in column 3. It would be greatly greatly appreciated if anyone be able to help in that department?

#### So to clarify, this post is no longer a discussion about methodology

I am hoping someone can help me produce a genetic algorithm to maximise the homology between the results of the equation

`adjusted xy = ((1-exp(-y*α)) * x/y)) + ((1-(1-exp(-y*α)))*Average xy)`

Where `adjusted xy` applies to each row of the csv. Maximising homology could be achieved by minimising the difference between the rank of the `adjusted xy` (where the rank is by each `Unique class` only) and `Achieved rank.`
Minimising this value would maximise the homology and essentially solve the problem presented to me of different size datasets.  If any more information is required please ask, I check this post about 20 times a day at the moment so should reply rather promptly. Many thanks SMNALLY.

Comment: [deleted my "condescending" answer.  it was meant to help, but clearly didn't.]

Comment: @andrewcooke Ok Ill delete my reply also, sorry I took offence. I have probably put too much content here, but It is because I wanted to leave the method open for discussion/crique rather than just providing an example. My background is in microbiology and radiochemistry and I normally consider my scientific logic quite good, but I didnt want to rule out the potential that there may already be established methods to overcome the problem presented.

Comment: As a point of clarity, do you want code that would implement what you described if given the value of α?  If so, then that would be a strait forward implementation.  Or do you want confirmation that your method works?  If that's the case, you might want to check out <http://math.stackexchange.com> or use a python implementation to check it empirically.

Comment: @randomusername Thanks for the reply, I believe the methodology to be sound so I am chasing the implimentation really but I thought I would leave my self open to scruteny just in case someone wanted to question it.

Comment: I don't know why this is tagged `scikit-learn` if you want to do something with GAs. There are no GAs in that package and none are planned, either.

Comment: @larsmans I will remove it from tags thanks

Comment: Could you please ellaborate a bit on the context of your data and the 'strike-rate'?

Comment: @A_A I have deliberately kept that information out of the question so as not to make it even more complex, the entire project is to do with identifying different subclasses of a cancer based on different numbers of repeated genetic markers for different expressed phenotypes. For instance 12/30 patients displaying phenotype 1 contained 5 repeats of genetic marker x. So the strike rate in this case would be 0.4 (12 / 30) Does this help? If not please ask again. :)

Comment: @SMNALLY: so effectively, you're trying to predict a probability? Then why don't you use logistic regresion?

Comment: I considered logistic regression, but this has exactly the same issue with some "strike rates" (i used it before so will continue to use that term) being generated from a larger dataset and others from a smaller one. Logistic regression as I know it certainly doesnt overcome the issue presented.

Comment: Added a 250 point bounty to this problem in the hope that someone will be able to help with the genetic algorithm suggested.

Comment: Well there is only 4 days left on my bounty, and I dont currently have enought to increase the bounty so please let me know if more detail or additional detail is required.

Comment: any advice or comments in how I should refine this question in an attempt to get this question solved?

Comment: Genetic Algorithms are never the right solution. We've had countless things better in every respect for decades now.

Comment: A quick list of the countless things better? Specifically targeting the problem described?

Comment: If you're estimating one single parameter? Binary search, Newton's algorithm, least squares, Max likelihood estimation. Take your pick. What would the genome look like anyways, in your genetic algorithm? one single value of alpha?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing sounds to me like ["Bias Variance Dilemna"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias-variance_dilemma) from a general point of view. In a nutshell, a more precise model favours variance (sensitivity to change in a single training set), a more general model favours bias (model works for many training sets)

May I suggest not to focus on GA but look at Instance Base Learning and advanced regression techniques.  The Andrew moore page at CMU is a [good entry point](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/).

And particularly [those slides](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/mbl08.pdf).

**[EDIT]**

After a second reading, here is my second understanding:

- You have a set of example data with two related attributes  X and Y.
- You do not want X/Y to dominate when Y is small, (considered as less representative).
- As a consequence you want to "weigth"  the examples with a adapted value adjusted_xy .
- You want adjusted_xy to be related to a third attribute  R (rank). Related such as,per class, adjusted_xy  is sorted like R.
- To do so you suggest to put it as an optimization problem,  searching for PARAMS of a given function  F(X,Y,PARAMS)= adjusted_xy .
- With the constraint that D=Distance( achieved rank for this class, rank of   adjusted_xy for this class ) is minimal.

Your question, at least for me, is in the field of attribute selection/attribute adaptation. (I guess the data set will later be used for supervised learning ).

One problem that I see in your approach (if well understood) is  that, at the end, rank will be highly related  to  adjusted_xy which  will bring therefore no interesting supplementary information.

Once this said, I think you surely know how GA works . You have to

- define the content of the chromosome : this appears to be your alpha parameter.
- define an appropriate fitness function

The fitness function for one individual can be a sum of distances over all examples of the dataset.

As  you are dealing with real values , other metaheuristics such as  Evolution Strategies (ES) or Simulated  Anealing may be more adapted than GA.

As solving optimization problems is cpu intensive, you might eventually consider C or Java instead of Python. (as fitness at least  will be interpreted and thus cost a lot).

Alternatively I would look at using Y as a weight to some supervised learning algorithm (if supervised learning is the target).

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will look into this for sure. I would be interested to hear your take on the proposed solution?

Comment: I enjoyed the locally weighted polynomial regression content and can forsee scenarios for its application in the future (within my project) however I am not sure I found anything to overcome the problem presented above.

Comment: any advice or comments in how I should refine this question in an attempt to get this question solved?

Comment: Thanks for the edit with your advice & comments. One point I wish to touch on, "at the end, rank will be highly related to adjusted_xy which will bring therefore no interesting supplementary information" I dont understand what the draw back to this is? Surly this is the idea of the suggested algorithm. Alter α in order to maximise homology between column 3 and rank of adjusted_xy.

Comment: I have not written a GA in any coding language before, my previous modeling experiences was using excel and solver (using their inbuilt evolutionary solving algorthm) I was hoping somone might be able to provide me with some sort of example realted to my data, which I could use as a backbone to edit for further GAs

Comment: @SMNALLY You can look at  a simple framework like [pygene] (http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pygene), it contains example with float genes .  First build a fitness function able to return  a normalized  score for a given alpha.

Comment: You can also use this fitness/scoring function with a simpler procedure such as Gradient Ascent (see SO for python examples).

Comment: @SMNALLY about 'homology': if used in a supervised learning setting, you will have two related attributes , carrying somehow the same information , this will confuse the learning algorithm. On the contrary its better to reduce the dimensionality (less attributes). This is why I talked about the Weights.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by the problem: You consider the fact that some features lead to some of your classes a 'strike'. You are taking a subset of your data and try to establish a rule for the strikes. You do establish one but then you notice that the accuracy of your rule depends on the volume of the dataset that was used to establish the 'strike' rate anyway. You are also commenting on the effect of some samples in biasing your 'strike' estimate.

1. The immediate answer is that it looks like you have a lot of variation in your data, therefore you will in one way or another need to collect more to account for that variation. (That is, variation that is inherent to the problem).
2. The fact that in some cases the numbers end up in 'unusable cases' could also be down to outliers. That is, measurements that are 'out of bounds' for a number of reasons and which you would have to find a way to either exclude them or re-adjust them. But this depends a lot on the context of the problem.
3. 'Strike rates' on their own will not help but they are perhaps a step towards the right direction. In any case, you can not compare strike rates if they are coming from samples of different sizes as you have found out too. If your problem is purely to determine the size of your sample so that your results conform to some specific accuracy then i would recommend that you have a look at [Statistical Power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power_) and how does the [sample size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size) affects it. But still, to determine the sample size you need to know a bit more about your data, which brings us back to point #1 about the inherent variation.
4. Therefore, my attempt to an answer is this: If i have understood your question correctly, you are dealing with a classification problem in which you seek to assign a number of items (patients) to a number of classes (types of cancer) on the evidence of some features (existence of genetic markers, or frequency of their appearance or any other quantity anyway) about these items. But, some features might not exist for all items or, there is a core group of features but there might be some more that do not appear all the time. The question now is, which classifier do you use to achieve this? Logistic regression was mentioned previously and has not helped. Therefore, what i would suggest is going for a Naive Bayesian Classifier. The classifier can be trained with the datasets you have used to derive the 'strike rates' which will provide the a-priori probabilities. When the classifier is 'running' it will be using the features of new data to construct a likelihood that the patient who provided this data should be assigned to each class.
   Perhaps the more common example for such a classifier is the [spam-email detectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering) where the likelihood that an email is spam is judged on the existence of specific words in the email (and a suitable training dataset that provides a good starting point of course).
5. Now, in terms of trying this out practically (and since your post is tagged with python related tags :) ), i would like to recommend [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). Weka contains a lot of related functionality including [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29) that could potentially help you with those differences in the size of the datasets. Although Weka is Java, [bindings exist for it in Python too](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/weka). I would definitely give it a go, the Weka package, book and community are very helpful.

Comment: Firstly you definately undestood the question and I really appreciate the answer and the time you have taken to write it. I have considered reformulating my data so as to be able to use a classifier as I have considered weighted least squares. See: pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels and pythonhosted.org/milk/randomforests.html I think I have firmly come to the conclusion now that the suggested method will overcome the issue, however I really believe that none of the ready available methods will fit my model as perfectly as the one suggested.

Comment: I will make sure this answer gets at least my upvote once I have accepted an answer, thank you again for your contribution :)

Comment: any advice or comments in how I should refine this question in an attempt to get this question solved?

Comment: I just had a look at the update. Can i just ask where are the 'α', 'x/y' and 'average x/y' come from? I suppose that this will end up being your 'fitness function' but before that, let's see if it could be framed as a simpler optimisation problem first. Other than that, if you are asking if there are any GA related packages in Python, then off the top of my head i would say DEAP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEAP_%28software%29). Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for Statistical Power. I felt something like that had to exist, not I know what's called and its definition.

Answer (score 2):

No. Don't use a genetic algorithm.

The bigger the search space of models and parameters, the better your chances of finding a good fit for your data points. But the less this fit will mean. Especially since for some groups your sample sizes are small and therefore the measurements have a high random component to them. This is why, somewhat counterintuitively, it is often actually harder to find a good model for your data after collecting it than before.

You have taken the question to the programmer's lair. This is not the place for it. We solve puzzles.

This is not a puzzle to find the best line through the dots.  You are searching for a model that makes sense and brings understanding on the subject matter. A genetic algorithm is very creative at line-through-dot drawing but will bring you little understanding.

Take the problem back where it belongs and ask the statisticians instead.

For a good model should be based on theory behind the data. It'll have to match the points on the right side of the graph, where (if I understand you right) most of the samples are. It'll be able to explain in hard probabilities how likely the deviations on the left are and tell you if they are significant or not.

If you do want to do some programming, I'd suggest you take the simplest linear model, add some random noise, and do a couple simulation runs for a population like your subjects. See if the data looks like the data you're looking at or if it generally 'looks' different, in which case there really is something nonlinear (and possibly interesting) going on on the left.

Comment: I have done linear based models, this is attempting to fix a known problem within said linear based models. Since I have a large quantity of data mazimising the homology of the ranks would give me the best fit. I will have a subsquent weighting based GA which will calculate whether or not it wishes to assign any weight to this modified parameter (in the multiparameter model) we are attempting to tune just one parameter here.

Comment: Have you done a statistical analysis of the deviation from the linear model? Is it a probable fit or not?

Comment: I apply the same statistical analysis to several linear models for different parameters within the same larger model. The deviation varies with each of these different parameters as a result of a varience in the average sized dataset accross these different parameters.

Comment: Exactly! So is the deviation for the smaller values within normal range or not? Does the deviation come from sample size and randomness or from a mechanism that isn't covered by the linear model? Making a better fit with a more intricate model won't tell you if it is fantasy or not, the fit or non-fit of the simple model will.

Comment: The models fit, and I have used them with great success but I am trying to iron out the creases here. In my larger multi parameter model I would use both adjusted x/y and standard x/y allowing the secondary GA to assign different weights to each of these. If as you suggest adjusted x/y isnt worth it, then this GA will weight this parameter as zero, and assign all the weight to the standard linear model of x/y. It is an experiment to try and improve a solution.

Comment: It won't end up at 0, but say it matches best for alpha = 2.45683 how will you tell if the new model models the random events which have already happened (and therefore has no predictive value) or if you have uncovered an underlying mechanism? Only a statistical analysis (or more experiments) can help you distinguish between the two.

Comment: Random events do happen, but by optimising the value of alpha through a GA with a dataset large enough it will provide a more accurate predictive value than the already used linear relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I once tackled a similar problem (as similar as problems like this ever are), in which there were many classes and high variance in features per data point. I personally used a Random Forest classifier (which I wrote in Java). Since your data is highly variant, and therefore hard to model, you could create multiple forests from different random samples of your large dataset and put a control layer on top to classify data against all the forests, then take the best score. I don't write python, but i found this link 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html
which may give you something to play with.

Comment: +1 for random forest, it's generally a good idea to use more than one tree ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Following [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), you must select a simpler model for small dataset and may want to switch to a more complex model as your dataset grows.

There are no [good] statistical tests that show you if a given model, in isolation, is a good predictor of your data. Or rather, a test may tell you that given model fitness is `N`, but you can never tell what the acceptable value of `N` is.

Thus, build several models and pick one with better tradeoff of predictive power and simplicity using [Akaike information criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). It has useful properties and not too hard to understand. :)

There are [other tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) of course, but AIC should get you started.

For a simple test, check out [p-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value)

Comment: Hello my dataset is more than 500,000 rows with the average Unique class conataining about 20 rows.

Comment: I think this should have been a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: too long for a comment

Comment: @SMNALLY it's not raw data count that matters. Consider on one end, [1,1,...,1] is fitted by constant no matter what size. On the other any three points can be fitted by 2nd deg poly, circle, sine, etc. You really need to consider what your data is, and once you fit it, how well it is fitted.

Comment: wrt. your data, 500K should be more than enough for everyone, but 20 rows per class means quite low confidence. If your data is precise and smooth, you can fit it nicely; but if it's noisy, your fit may be completely random.